# pdflatex: encoding problems for macros defined before documenclass

Tags: pdftex, input-encodings

I use `pdflatex` to create a bunch of personalised documents. From a list of names I generate tex files for each John and Jane Doe of the form:

```
\newcommand{\firstname}{John}
\newcommand{\lastname}{Doe}
\input{thedocument.tex}
```

and then simply run `pdflatex` on each resulting tex file.

However, I'm experiencing encoding problems with this approach if the people are for example `Jöhn` and `Jäne` and their names will come out as `Jhn` and `Jne`, respectively.

I don't know how to fix this.

- `file johndoe.tex` says `TeX document, ISO-8859 text, with no line terminators`
- `file thedocument.tex` says `LaTeX 2e document, ISO-8859 text`

In `thedocument.tex` I have a line `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`. I tried it with the `utf8` option but then `pdflatex` fails at the first not ascii character in `thedocument.tex`. I tried a few other options; every `latinN` results in broken names and everything else results in `pdflatex` failing.

As all the other special characters in `thedocument.tex` work and the file types seem identical, I'm guessing that my problem has to do with `\firstname` and `\lastname` being specified before `\documentclass`. Could that be the case? How can I fix this?

Comment: Generate `\documentclass` and `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` in the beginning of `johndoe.tex` and remove them from `thedocument.tex`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\firstname}{Jöhn}
\newcommand{\lastname}{Jäne }
\input{thedocument.tex}
```

where `utf8` has to match the encoding used. Use `latin1` if the file is in ISO-8859-1.

Then don't load `\usepackage{inputenc}` in the main document, or load it with the same option.

Comment: Works, thanks! Painfully obvious solution. :-(